# Remove out nested array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this nested array

```
let arr = [['first', 'second'], ['third', 'fourth'], ['second', 'third']]
```

now I want to filter/remove based on exactly this array.

```
let filter = ['first', 'second']
```

and now my expected output should be:

```
[['third', 'fourth'], ['second', 'third']]
```

I only have this piece of code:

```
arr.filter(str => str.indexOf('second') === -1)
```

Which doesn't give the expected output, it also removed `['second', 'third']` because it filters whatever element that contains **'second'**.. so they must be a better way or an improvement to the code.

Comment: What are you expecting from `['second', 'third']`?

Comment: Why are you filtering with `str` when the elements are arrays? `str` is a bad name.

Comment: str is just a poorly named variable that contains an array

Comment: @CertainPerformance  nothing, I just want to remove out exactly whatever I put to filter variable if there is such nested array.

Comment: So the result from `['second', 'third']` should be nothing, `[]`? Is it because every `arr` subarray has at least one item? The logic you're looking for is quite unclear ATM

Comment: The description is not clear to me either. If target is `["a", "b"]` and the array is `[["b", "a"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "a", "b", "c"]]` for example, what happens and why? Please edit the post to show a variety of examples that clearly illustrate the logic--i.e., should an element be filtered out if it is an exact match in any order for every element or ...?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks--so you want to remove any elements that are an exact match on the target array? What about dupes/ordering?

Comment: @ggorlen they will be no dupes and ordering doesn't matter also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about ordering and need exact matches, you can write a simple arrays equal method and then filter out any equal arrays:

```js
const arrEq = (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every((e, i) => b[i] === e);

const arr = [['first', 'second'], ['third', 'fourth'], ['second', 'third']];
const filter = ['first', 'second'];

console.log(arr.filter(e => !arrEq(e, filter)));
```

If you want the same elements but order doesn't matter:

```js
const arrItemsEq = (a, b, cmp) => {
  if (a.length !== b.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  a = a.slice().sort(cmp);
  b = b.slice().sort(cmp);
  return a.every((e, i) => e === b[i]);
};

const arr = [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"]];
const filter = ["b", "a"];

const strCmp = (x, y) => x.localeCompare(y);
console.log(arr.filter(e => !arrItemsEq(e, filter, strCmp)));
```

If you want to filter out `arr` elements if they don't include at least one of each `filter` element:

```js
const arr = [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"]];
const filter = ["b", "a"];

console.log(arr.filter(x => !filter.every(y => x.includes(y))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to check if the element doesn't include every string of the filter array.

```js
let arr = [['first', 'second'], ['third', 'fourth'], ['second', 'third']]

let filterout = ['first', 'second']

let arr2 = arr.filter(x => ! filterout.every(y => x.includes(y)))

console.log(arr2)
```

But by using `filter` it basically creates a new array with fewer elements.  Which is good enough for a small array.

If if the goal is to directly change the original array, then those elements can be spliced from that array.

```js
let arr = [ ['first', 'second'], ['third', 'fourth'], ['second', 'third'], ['second', 'first'] ]

let filterout = ['first', 'second']

// getting the indexes of the element that need to be removed
let idxArr = []
arr.forEach( (x, idx) => { if(x.every(y => filterout.includes(y))) idxArr.push(idx)})

// removing the elements from the array
idxArr.sort((i,j)=>j-i).forEach(idx => {arr.splice(idx, 1)})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test two arrays for equality. [There are many ways to do it] but once you pick one, you can simply remove any array that is equal to another. To avoid reimplementing the wheel, I'll use the [LoDash `_.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) for demonstration purposes:

```js
let arr = [['first', 'second'], ['third', 'fourth']]

let filter = ['first', 'second']

let result = arr.filter(item => !_.isEqual(filter, item));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The equality function can be swapped to any implementation that satisfies you. A very simple one is simply:

```
function isEqual(a, b) {
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
}
```

but it's not guaranteed to be correct (e.g, `isEqual([1, 2], ["1,2"]) //true`) and it's going to be slow with large inputs. But it might still work, depending on circumstances.